# URL-handler for linux with install4j not working

Tags: linux, install4j

I've defined an URL handler for my application. It work's perfectly for Windows and Mac but on Linux it doesn't seem to get installed at all. At least in some earlier version of install4j (unfortunately not sure which one) it got installed as an `xdg-mime` but that doesn't happen now. Has anyone got URL handlers working on Linux with install4j (I'm on version 9.0.6)?

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com with an include the .install4j/installation.log file as well as the .install4j project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from ej-technologies:
*On Linux, an URL handler association requires a desktop file to be created for the launcher. install4j does this either with the "Create program group" action or with the "Create start menu entry" action.*

So the launcher used by the URL handler MUST have the "Integrate into menus..." option set OR be set in an "Create start menu entry" action in order to work on Linux.